# How to see all users who have same grant

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb, privilege

I want to list the user who have a common privilege.
For example, I wwant to liste all users who cant execute a specific stored procedure.

Any ideas ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this :

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.user_privileges where PRIVILEGE_TYPE ="TRIGGER"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user WHERE Execute_priv = 'N';
```

or

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.grantee
    FROM  information_schema.user_privileges AS a
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT  *
            FROM  information_schema.user_privileges
            WHERE  grantee = a.grantee
              AND  privilege_type = "EXECUTE" 
                     );
```